# How to Make Page refresh in flutter with both Scroll and Btn

Tags: flutter, widget

I Know we can make flutter page refresh with scrolling using refreshIndicator And also we can use the Btn to refresh the page But is there any way so that we can achieve both of these in the same widget.

I tried Using refreshIndicator but its working only either for a scroll or for the button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: use ListView instead of column/SingleChildScrollView.